# adding layout to tabs on bokeh dashboard

Tags: layout, tabs, bokeh

I'm exploring the bokeh library. 
I tried to add several plots to each tab using VBox, but it did not work.
I read somewhere that tabs & VBox/HBox cannot be used together.
How do I handle the layout on the tabs then?

Modified example to add several elements per tab:

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.widgets.layouts import VBox
output_file("slider.html")
p1 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p1.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)

p2 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p2.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=3, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
p=VBox(p1,p2)
tab1 = Panel(child=p,title="circle")
tab2 = Panel(child=p2, title="line")
tabs = Tabs(tabs=[ tab1, tab2 ])
show(tabs)
```

Example from the website:

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("slider.html")

p1 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p1.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
tab1 = Panel(child=p1, title="circle")

p2 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p2.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=3, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
tab2 = Panel(child=p2, title="line")

tabs = Tabs(tabs=[ tab1, tab2 ])

show(tabs)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure about using HBox and VBox with Tabs, but you can use `layout` to arrange things in tabs, it has worked well for me and I think is a bit more flexible than the other options. Here's a quick example I think works:

```
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.models.widgets import Tabs, Panel
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure

fig1 = figure()
fig1.circle([0,1,2],[1,3,2])
fig2 = figure()
fig2.circle([0,0,2],[4,-1,1])
fig3 = figure()
fig3.circle([0,4,3],[1,2,0])

l1 = layout([[fig1, fig2]], sizing_mode='fixed')
l2 = layout([[fig3]],sizing_mode='fixed')

tab1 = Panel(child=l1,title="This is Tab 1")
tab2 = Panel(child=l2,title="This is Tab 2")
tabs = Tabs(tabs=[ tab1, tab2 ])

curdoc().add_root(tabs)
```

I found the movies example very useful for all sorts of stuff, the code for which is [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/movies/main.py), and well worth a look.